# PostgreSQL and Tableau

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

I'm trying to connect my Tableau desktop to a PostgreSQL database on a virtual machine. I keep getting this error unable to connect to the server "xx.xx.xxx.xxx". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database. Is there any way to solve the problem?

I have enabled access in the virtual machine via the pg_hba conf file and I can access it from pgAdmin4 in my PC.

For the server text box in tableau, I'm just putting the IP of the virtual machine. The rest of the boxes are just default settings (besides password).

Comment: Are you sure it's not on a different port than the default?

Comment: Yeah, the port is the same (5432). Should the ports be different?